# Update navigation bar back button image for the whole project

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I need to update the navigation bar back button image for the whole project some sort I achieved this from the code below, But the problem is back button is showing two adjacent lines which are un wanted for me. Please guide me is there any code to remove those lines.

```
let image = UIImage(named:"backButton")
        let backImage = image?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal).resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 13, 0, 6))

        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backImage, forState: .Normal, barMetrics: .Default)
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(-400, 0), forBarMetrics: .Default)
```

[image]

Comment: Check your image, looks like it consist of white lines?

Comment: @iphonic it doesn't have actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These 2 lines are parts of the distorted `backButton` image that appear because of the incorrect cap insets. Setting caps to cover the whole image would help. e.g.:

```
if let image = UIImage(named:"backButton"){
    let backImage = image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal).resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(image.size.height, image.size.width, 0, 0))
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backImage, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
    UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(-400, 0), for: .default)
}
```

(Swift 3)

Comment: @Vishnuvardhan Could you please provide the `backButton` image you use (via Dropbox of smth like that)?

Comment: You are correct, it was due to the wrong image insets as well I was using the .pdf image now I replaced that one to png image now it's solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add the bar button item on the view at storyboard, 
- click bar button item,
- choose attributes inspector,
- under Bar Item section,
- you can select image or define others.